# How can I fix my desktop background setting?

Tags: unity, gnome, desktop-environments, appearance

I am running Ubuntu 13.10. I installed gnome3 out of curiosity a few days back, from then my desktop background just went black. It won't change no matter what I do. I removed gnome completely and reinstalled Unity. But the problem persists. Hoping to find some help here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue:
I turned the desktop icons off using Ubuntu Tweak and from the following restart I had a black wallpaper.
To get my wallpaper back I turned desktop icons on using Ubuntu Tweak again.

Downoad Ubuntu Tweak: http://ubuntu-tweak.com/
Ubuntu Tweak->Tweaks->Desktop icon settings->Show icons on the desktop->ON
[image]
Restart then.

If you don't have the desktop icons in addition to the wallpaper then you can give this a try.

Comment: Hey it actually worked, I turned on the desktop icons and wallpaper came back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is to hit open a Terminal or hit Alt-F2 and run the command:
unity --reset.

If this doesn't work, (most likely it won't),for 13.10 follow this [link](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/04/how-to-reset-unity-compiz-in-ubuntu-12-10-and-13-04)

Comment: What about in 13.10? The user specifically mentioned he's using 13.10.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.